# binary maximum and minimum number limitation of int type in Java

Tags: java, binary, numbers, int

Why is the binary maximum and minimum number limitation shown as below:

```
//0 11111110 11111111111111111111111
int maxInt=0x7fffffff;

//0 00000001 00000000000000000000000
int minInt=0x80000000;
```

why is it not shown as below:

```
int maxInt=0xffffffff;

int minInt=0x00000000;
```

Comment: because you need to handle negatives too.

Comment: cause it is signed .

Comment: I don't get your binary number for the max `int` when I convert using a calculator.

Comment: Read how two's complement number storage works.

Comment: I don't understand the `11111110` in your first line at all.  How did you get that?